# Display an image for a TreeNode

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, iis, treeview

I try to display Images at a node in a Treeview. The Treeview is in an ascx control cause i need it multiple times.

I use the following code:

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="FolderTree" runat="server"  BackColor="White">
            <NodeStyle ForeColor="Black" ImageUrl="~/App_GlobalResources/folderClosed.png" />
            <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/App_GlobalResources/folderOpen.png" />
            <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/App_GlobalResources/folderOpen.png" />
        </asp:TreeView>
```

Thsi code semms to be right for me, and its also displayed right in the designer.

But when i start the page, not a single picture is shown. Only the default collapsebuttons are visible.
What am i doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: I added the code how i populate the control

```
 private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                var devData = Foo.GetDevices(); // returns a list with all devices
                    foreach (string temp in devData)
                    {
                        this.FolderTree.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Text = temp, ImageUrl = "~/App_GlobalResources/folderOpen.png" });
                    }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            //errorhandling
        }
    }
```

Edit 2: I **assume** i have that bug:  [forums.asp.net/t/943367.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/t/943367.aspx) but the suggested Solution isnt working! (see code above, i already set the value via code. Does anybody know a solution/ a hotfix (to use in an webusercontrol(.ascx))?

I also tried (on my base site):

```
 protected override void OnSaveStateComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tmpNode in this.LeftSelectControl.AccessFolderView.Nodes) //AccessFolderView = var, which contains the treeview of the ascx (to access it)
        {
            tmpNode.ImageUrl = "~/App_GlobalResources/folderOpen.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you populate the tree?

Comment: By Code. I can add it. Wait a second.

Comment: @Arion: I added the baseic code.FileSystemInteract.GetDevices();  returns a list with alll currently connected devicenames ("C:\\"... etc) If the user collapse a node, there is a similar method which adds childnodes with the containig folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DHTMLX Tree View` a Open source javascript library that combines well in C# Fluidly. It will produce nice tree view with images.

Its very simple to use in C# aspx page.

[Click Here for Dhtmlx tree](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/samples/01_appearance/11_tree_text_image.html)

Answer (score 1):

Never done the way you styled your TreeView.
But this is how i style my Treeview. Hope it helps you.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="treeView" runat="server" NodeIndent="20" ExpandDepth="0" NodeStyle-HorizontalPadding="2"
            ShowLines="true" ExpandImageUrl="../images/Open_Folder.png" CollapseImageUrl="../images/Close_Folder.png"
            ForeColor="Black">
</asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: Funny: I tried it and it is shown correctly in designer, but also if i start the page nothing only the defaults are displayed

Comment: no effect. I also tryed harcdcoded and dynamic paths for the pictures

Comment: when i replace the image path with my images path its working perfectly. if you can verify the image path and whether the images are present in the folder and are included in the project. Or try replacing the "~" with "../"

Comment: They are 100% percent ok. I found the following: http://forums.asp.net/t/943367.aspx Thsi seems to be a Bug. Sdly it semms that i can do nothing, even setting the paths in code does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution: Dont use App_GlobalResources.

I wont mark this as answer cause this was an stupid mistake by me. You can access App_* Folders only serverside, not clientside.